# Binding to Collection inside Listbox causes TwoWay binding to not work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, listbox

I'm having issues with binding a collection to text boxes in a ListBox (code below). I've done several google searches, but can't seem to find anything relevant to my particular sitation.

I've found that when I have a ContentControl with a DataTemplate that consists of only a TextBox and the associated binding to a single property, the set and get all works correctly (setting the textbox sets the bound value, etc), but when the TextBox is part of the ItemTemplate for a ListBox, it doesn't work for setting the value, but if the underlying value is changed, it bubbles up to change the TextBox just fine.

In this case, the collection is made up of objects (as in the type) and not a class type, so the binding isn't to a particular property, it's to the object itself, which means that in order to specify a TwoWay binding (which I'm not sure I should have to do), I have to put in the "Path=." to refer to the current item in the collection. The singular property is just linked to the first element of the collection.

I have added a TestValueConverter which doesn't do anything except give me some convenient places to put breakpoints when the underlying value is actually read and set.

MainWindow.xaml

```
    <Window x:Class="CollectionDataTemplateTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CollectionDataTemplateTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>

        <!--,diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High-->

        <local:TestValueConverter x:Key="TestValueConverter"/>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="TestParamValueEditArrayTemplate">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Values}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource TestValueConverter},diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" 
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="200" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ParamValueEditNonArrayTemplate">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource TestValueConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <GroupBox Header="Array">
            <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TestParamValueEditArrayTemplate}"
                            Content="{Binding Path=model}"/>
        </GroupBox>

        <GroupBox Header="Non Array">
            <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ParamValueEditNonArrayTemplate}"
                            Content="{Binding Path=model}"/>
        </GroupBox>

        <Button MinWidth="40">Not used</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace CollectionDataTemplateTest
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public class Model
        {
            private ObservableCollection<object> values;

            public object Value
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.values[0];
                }
                set
                {
                    this.values[0] = value;
                }
            }

            public ObservableCollection<object> Values
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.values;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.values = value;
                }
            }

            public Model()
            {
                this.values = new ObservableCollection<object>();

                this.values.Add(5);
            }
        }

        public Model model
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.model = new Model();
            this.DataContext = this;

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

TestValueConverter.cs

```
namespace CollectionDataTemplateTest
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Data;

    public class TestValueConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

So, I'm obviously missing something here in the way that bindings happen to the elements of a Collection property.

Any ideas?

Comment: I could be wrong, but the Binding you use for your textbox:

{Binding **Path=.**,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource TestValueConverter},diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}

The 'Path=.' part seems very fishy to me. Have you tried just removing the Path attribute completely?

Comment: You cannot 2-way bind to `Path=.` because the runtime does not know what to do with the new value (because it does not know the setter of the parent). If you describe your actual problem, there might be another way.

Comment: That makes sense, and pretty much matches what I thought.

I basically have a UserControl that contains controls to edit either a single value, or an array of values, and I'm using a DataTemplateSelector to select between the two DataTemplates.

I put the TwoWay binding on because initially the binding wasn't working (due to this issue), and I saw that the default was OneWay, and so tried for 2 way binding.

Basically I need a DataTemplate that binds to and displays the elements in an ObservableCollection and allows me to edit those elements (via text box preferably, but not set in stone).